# C# Razor Pages, Accessing variable from an instantiated class instantiated from another class that is instantiated from model, very basic question

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I have a class with a variable in it.  I instantiate that class from another class and instantiate that class from Index.cshtml.cs.  I'm trying to access the variable in the original class from Index.cshtml however I'm getting various error depending on the word combinations I try.

Class

```
public class Aclass
{
    public string AString;
}

public class Bclass
{
    Aclass A1= new Aclass ();
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
public void OnGet()
{
    Bclass DataRaw = new Bclass();
}
```

Index.cshtml

How do I access AString from the Razor page?

1 example: @IndexModel.DataRaw.AString - error: IndexModel does not contain a definition of DataRaw.
etc

I realise this is a very basic question but I have only ever seen information about 1 level of instantiation.

Comment: You cannot access DataRaw because it is within the scope of OnGet().  Change the scope of the variable and make it public.

Comment: @hijinxbassist - You should add that as the answer with the code example of what you mean because that is correct.

Comment: I have tried putting the definition (public Bclass DataRaw = new Bclass();) between the (public class IndexModel) and the (public void OnGet()), and get the same error on the Index.cshtml page..

Comment: Sorry I have not used Razor Pages, trying to work up a example for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable DataRaw is currently in the scope of the `OnGet` function, meaning that is the only place the variable is accessible.  Move the variable outside of the function, into the class body.

```
public class Index : PageModel
{
    public Bclass DataRaw { get; set; } = new Bclass();

    ...
}
```

You also need to make A1 inside of Bclass `public` in order to access it.

```
public class Bclass
{
    public Aclass A1 = new Aclass();
}
```

Then access your variable in the cshtml page

```
<p>
    @Model.DataRaw.A1.AString
</p>
```

Comment: Thankyou, that has solved my problem.  I also had to make it static, i.e. public static Bclass DataRaw etc. or it would give me an Object reference is required for non-static etc.

Comment: You should not need to make it static unless you did `Index.DataRaw....`

Comment: Yep, another problem solved.